# opencv - image stitch use of vector<vector<Rect> > rois

Tags: c++, opencv, image-stitching

I'm having trouble specifying the "region of interests" to perform feature finding in image stitching method (Stitcher::stitch). I get the following error

"OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= roi.x && 0 <= roi.width && roi.x + roi.width <= m.cols && 0 <= roi.y && 0 <= roi.height && roi.y + roi.height <= m.rows) in Mat, file /Users/Aziz/Documents/Projects/opencv_sources/trunk/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 308
terminate called throwing an exception"

but when I checked the regions and the image cols and rows, it seems to be fine. Any help of suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you have everything the correct way round? cv::Mat ctor is (rows,cols) but roi rect is (x,y,cols,rows) that's got me a few times

Comment: I tried swapping the rows and cols.. no luck with that either. Do you have any examples of using Vector<vector<Rect> > roes in opencv?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV 2.4.0 have bug in `Stitcher::Status Stitcher::matchImages()` method (stiicher.cpp):
the algo scales the input image but the input roi remain unchanged.

Comment: But I'm using a older version of opencv and stitching takes a lot of time.. anyways to improve it?

Comment: I have examined the svn-logs of stitcher.cpp file and found no changes in ROIs (after adding this feature to OpenCV stitcher). I made changes to the library to solve my problem and error. But my changes is not tested yet unfortunatly.